# CreateBubblePopup issue IE 9.0.1

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, popup

Why is it that CreateBubblePopup doesn't work in IE 9 while it supposedly worked in previous versions? Is there a way to make it work or not?

To test: http://www.vegabit.com/Examples/different-elements.html

Comment: Have you asked the person who made it?

Comment: Works fine in IE 9.0.8112.16421

Answer (score 1):

It works on IE9, when I tried it.

Comment: @Adam, if it doesn't work in jQuery 1.6.2, I'd ask the developer to fix it.  http://maxvergelli.wordpress.com/jquery-bubble-popup/